# Visual Studio, Make scorch without command

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

Is there possible to execute the scorch command for TFS in Visual Studio, without using the command line?

If yes, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the TFPT Scorch command in a script file, and add the script to Pre-build script path in the build definition. Then the TFPT Scorch command will be called during the TFS build process.

For example, the screenshot bellows shows that the PreBuild.ps1 PowerShell script is added to the build process.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. So apparently, there is no default button to do that in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, you need to at least put the TFPT Scorch command in one script file.